# How to derive a score (ranking) based on multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below :

```
User_ID Game_ID Liked   Shared  Category
1       11       Y       N      Music
1       11       Y       N      Music
1       22       Y       Y      Music
1       11       Y       N      Music
1       33       N       N      Dance
2       33       N       Y      Dance
2       44       Y       Y      Peace
2       11       N       N      Music
```

I need to derive a new column `Rating` with the below logic:

1. For a particular `User_ID` : If for a particular `Game_ID`, both `Liked` and `Shared` is `Y` then `Score = 2`, if any one is `Y`, then `Score = 1`, else `Score = 0`.
2. For a particular `User_ID` : If a `Game_ID` is repeated more than 2 times  then `Score = 2`, if 2 times then `1`, else `Score = 0`.
3. For a particular `User_ID` : If a `Game_ID` belongs to `Category` which is the Top Category the `Score = 1`, else `Score = 0`

   Eg : `User_ID = 1`, `Top Category = Music` ( as its frequency count is 4 out 5 ), all `Game_ID` in `Music` category for this user will get Score of `1`.

   Finally for we need the cumulative score for each `User_ID` - `Game_ID`.
     Eg : `User_ID = 1`, `Game_ID = 11`.

   1) Liked / Shared = Any one is `Y` - `Score = 1`

   2) `Category` of that `Game_ID` belongs to Top Category (Music) for that User_ID so `Score : 1`

   3) `Game_ID` is repeated more than twice for this `User_ID` - `Score : 2`
       Cumulative Score : `1+1+2 = 4`

Below is the expected output :

```
User_ID Game_ID Like/Share  Category    Game_repeat Rating
      1      11          1         1              2      4
      1      22          2         1              0      3
      1      33          0         0              0      0
      2      33          1         0              0      1
      2      44          2         0              0      2
      2      11          0         0              0      0
```

NOTE: In the expected output, only User_ID, Game_ID and Rating is vital.
       Remaining columns are just for details.

Can you friends help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df['Cond1'] = (df['Liked'] == 'Y').astype(int) + (df['Shared'] == 'Y').astype(int)

df['Cond2'] = df.groupby(['User_ID','Game_ID'])['Game_ID'].transform('size').sub(1).clip(0,2)

df['Cond3'] = df.groupby('User_ID')['Category'].apply(lambda x: ((x.value_counts().head(1).index[0] == x) & (x.value_counts().head(1).values[0] > 1).astype(int)))

df['Score'] = df['Cond1'] + df['Cond2'] + df['Cond3']

df_out = df.groupby(['User_ID','Game_ID'])['Score'].max().reset_index()

df_out
```

Output:

```
   User_ID  Game_ID  Score
0        1       11      4
1        1       22      3
2        1       33      0
3        2       11      0
4        2       33      1
5        2       44      2
```

Comment: Just in case if i want to change the condition df['Cond2'] if its repeated more than 3 times make it score as 2 , 2 times then score as 1, if 1 times score as 0.5. How do we further change it ?

Comment: What if it appears exactly 3 times?

Comment: Yes, need to count that as well. Just wanted to understand further if changes required on the logic how it can be handled. As that would be more flexible.

Comment: To understand the logic of #2, get the size of each group of User and Game.  Now, I subtract 1, if it appears twice in the original problem you wanted a value of 1.  Do does an exact count of three score 2 or score 1?  If it scores 1, the we might need to use np.select.